# Stopwords eliminating and vector making

Tags: r, text-mining, stop-words

In text2vec, the only function I could find about Stopwords is “create_vocabulary”. But in text mining mission, we usually need to eliminate the stopwords in the resource document and then build corpus or other further processes. How do we use “stopword” to tackle the documents in building corpus, dtm and tcm using text2vec?

I’ve used tm for text mining before. It has a function for analyzing PDF document, but it reads one paper as several vectors(one line, one vector), not read each of the document as a vector as my expect. Furthermore, the format exchange function in tm have mess code problem in Chinese. If use text2vec to read documents, could it read one paper into a vector?(aka. Is the volume of vector large enough for one paper published on journals?) Otherwise, the corpus and vector built in text2vec compatible with which built in tm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to create document-term matrix:

1. Using feature hashing
2. Using vocabulary

See [text-vectorization vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/text2vec/vignettes/text-vectorization.html) for details.

You are interesting in 2 choice. This mean you should build vocabulary - set of words/ngrams which will be used in all downstream tasks. `create_vocabulary` creates vocabulary object and only terms from this object will be used in further steps. So if you will provide `stopwords` to `create_vocabulary`, it will remove them from the set of all observed words in the corpus.As you can see you should provide stopwords only once. All the dowstream tasks will work with vocabulary.

Answer on second question.

`text2vec` doesn't provide high-level functions for reading PDF documents. However it allows user to provide custom reader function. All you need is to read full articles with some function and reshape them to character vector where each element corresponds to desired unit of information (full article, paragraph, etc). For example you can easily combine lines into single element with `paste()` function. For example:

```
article = c("sentence 1.", "sentence 2")
full_article = paste(article, collapse = ' ')
#  "sentence 1. sentence 2"
```

Hope this helps.